# Browser notification using AWS SNS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am new to Amazon services. I already used FIREBASE and PUBNUB for browser notification in other applications. I would like to build browser notification like FIREBASE or PUBNUB using AWS SNS.

For web application front end I am using ReactJs and back-end Nodejs lambda functions.

Is it possible to use SNS for Browser or Web application Notification? 
Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444435/sns-notifications-to-browser?rq=1 is similar question.

Answer (score 11):

You can use AWS IOT Websockets or AWS AppSync for This. Following articles will give you an overview of using these technologies.

- [Realtime Serverless Web Apps with AWS](https://codeburst.io/realtime-serverless-web-apps-with-aws-5db74eda34ea) to get an overview of the usage.
- [Receiving AWS IoT messages in your browser using websockets](https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357) to understand in using AWS IOT for Notifications.
- [Building a JavaScript Client App](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-javascript.html) which is useful as a tutorial for AppSync.

Out of AWS AppSync and AWS IOT, I would recommend AppSync due to its support for JavaScript Frameworks.

**Note**: However, with AWS SNS, this is not possible in browsers (But possible for mobile applications with Push Notifications).

Answer (score 5):

AWS SNS doesn't support web push. Its said that they are planning to but long time ago.
[Developer Forum Entry](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182684)

> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> Currently SNS does not support Chrome push but we are considering
>   adding support for it.
>
> Regards, George

I came across to some solutions to this using middlewares. Have a look.

[deepstreamhub](https://deepstreamhub.com/blog/publishing-aws-sns-messages-to-browsers-tutorial/)

[pushkin](https://github.com/gdnmobilelab/pushkin)